# Is there a standard C function for computing the string length up to some limit?

Tags: c, string

Consider a situation: I have a buffer of known length that presumably stores a null-terminated string and I need to know the length of the string.

The problem is if I use `strlen()` *and* the string turns out to be *not null-terminated* the program runs into undefined behavior while reading beyond the buffer end. So I'd like to have a function like the following:

```
 size_t strlenUpTo( char* buffer, size_t limit )
 {
     size_t count = 0;
     while( count < limit && *buffer != 0 ) {
        count++;
        buffer++;
     }
     return count;
 }
```

so that it returns the length of the string but never tries to read beyond the buffer end.

Is there such function already in C library or do I have to use my own?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `memchr(string, 0, limit)`, as in:

```
size_t strlenUpTo(char *s, size_t n)
{
    char *z = memchr(s, 0, n);
    return z ? z-s : n;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

According to my documentation, POSIX has `size_t strnlen(const char *src, size_t maxlen);`

```
n = strnlen("foobar", 7); // n = 6;
n = strnlen("foobar", 6); // n = 6;
n = strnlen("foobar", 5); // n = 5;
```

Comment: Note that if your system doesn't have `strnlen`, you can use my answer as a drop-in replacement. Naming the replacement `strnlen` and ensuring that it has identical semantics to the POSIX `strnlen` function is probably nicer than making a differently-named and possibly differently-behaved version.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `strnlen`.  This is it's manpage:

```
NAME
       strnlen - determine the length of a fixed-size string

SYNOPSIS
       #include <string.h>

       size_t strnlen(const char *s, size_t maxlen);

DESCRIPTION
       The  strnlen  function returns the number of characters in
       the string pointed to by s, not including the  terminating
       '\0' character, but at most maxlen. In doing this, strnlen
       looks only at the first maxlen characters at s  and  never
       beyond s+maxlen.

RETURN VALUE
       The  strnlen  function  returns strlen(s), if that is less
       than maxlen, or maxlen if there is no '\0' character among
       the first maxlen characters pointed to by s.

CONFORMING TO
       This function is a GNU extension.

SEE ALSO
       strlen(3)
```

Comment: Note the CONFORMING TO section. It's outdated though; POSIX 2008 standardized this function. But of course it's still not plain C.